# How do [feature-request] questions work with [status-*] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I was searching for the following type of information about "feature requests" and the status they eventually get:

- Who decides when the status of a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) question should be assigned?
- Are there any rules about how soon the status should be assigned?
- Should I give my own input on a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) question, even though it is now declined? If I think more could be added to such a question, or that situations have changed enough, should I ask a new [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or add to the old one?

Answer (score 5):

Every meta question needs to be classified as a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [support](/questions/tagged/support), and/or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) post.<sup>1</sup>  Pick at least one of those tags when you submit your question, using your best judgement.  (On other sites, such as [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com), those required tags are distinguished by colour.  It's harder to see the distinction on Meta Code Review.)

The red tags — [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), and [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced), and [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) — can only be added by moderators and Stack Exchange staff.  We do our best to assign a status when the desired direction is clear, based on considerations such as community consensus, available resources, Stack Exchange policy, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup> Apparently, moderators are [exempt from this rule](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/53465/148099).

Answer (score 3):

> Who decides when the status of a "feature-request" question should be assigned?

Moderators or employees. Usually that is only done by employees, though. Sometimes when there is preexisting consensus or previous questions about the same [feature-request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), moderators may tag a question with the appropriate tag, and then close as duplicate.

In general the [status-*] tags are reserved for employees, though. This means, Devs and CMs assign these, when company-internal discussion has come to a consensus. In edge-cases they also refer to previously established community-consensus, but that's seldom.

> Are there any rules about how soon the status should be assigned?

No. This happens when the people in charge get around to it. But when a status is assigned, that status is usually final, and as such status assignment happens after quite some time.

> Should I give my own input on a "status-declined" question, even
>   though it is now declined?

Sure you may do so, but from my experience there's seldom necessity to do such, unless the situation changed significantly.

> If I think more could be added to such a question, or that situations
>   have changed enough, should I ask a new feature-request or add to the
>   old?

If you want to add to the old question, you should do that. But for significant change of situation, it is advisable to create a new question, linking back to the previous question and explaining the differences.

Comment: Some status tags, such as "completed" and "declined," can still be used as mods.  It just depends on the particular question.  It's just employees that use tags such as [meta-tag:status-norepro], [meta-tag:status-reproduced], and [meta-tag:status-bydesign]